# SOLR storing data from relational database

Tags: solr

Question regarding data storing concept in SOLR
I will have three documents:

User with:
   - id (unique)
   - CompanyName
   - Address

Property:
   - isCarOwner
   - Car type

Location with:
   - Address

Data will be collected from Relational database. Question is how do I represent this data in solr.

In my head I have this concept:
I will have one document that will have all these fields defined. And I will feed that document as a collection of data from relational database. I will use this:

I will fill this index with following query (8983/solr/update/json?commit=true):

```
[{
"id" : "1",
"companyname" : "BlackDevil",
"iscarowner": true,
"cartype": "Honda R1",
"Address": "Super Hero Street."
}]
```

I will search this index with the following query:

```
:8983/solr/select?q=id:1&wt=json&indent=true
```

DataSet is much bigger than this, but this is only a concept. Is this the right approach?

My main source of problem is this: Is one index sufficient for this? Do I need to expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original tables have 1-1 relationships (one user, 0 or 1 car type, 0 or 1 address) then yes, your approach is the right one for Solr - certainly the simplest.

More complex relations in the original data can be handled in different ways (multi-value fields, nested documents, multiple cores), but from your description you don't need any of this. One flat collection with all the info in each document will work beautifully - and again is the "default" way of working with Solr.